# why fn return &str, consider using the `'static` lifetime: `&'static `, but struct fn is correct?

Tags: rust

why fn return &str should static lifetime, but struct's fn not?

```rs
fn say() -> &str {
    "this is str"
}
// consider using the `'static` lifetime: `&'static `
```

but cat.hi ,is correct

```rs
struct Cat {}
impl Cat {
    fn hi(&self) -> &str {
        "hi"
    }
}
```

why fn return &str tips consider using the `'static` lifetime: `&'static` , but struct fn not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general every reference needs a lifetime. The compiler will autocomplete them in some cases. These cases are described here https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html.

There is no rule for the first example, so you have to provide a lifetime.

In your second example the rule `If there are multiple input lifetime positions, but one of them is &self or &mut self, the lifetime of self is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.` is applied which makes it to

```
struct Cat {}
impl Cat {
    fn hi<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str {
        "hi"
    }
}
```

Which is actually different from

```
struct Cat {}
impl Cat {
    fn hi<'a>(&'a self) -> &'static str {
        "hi"
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that actually the second is the correct to use, usually.